# Deploy Java EE application as root context on WildFly

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I'm using Eclipse Mars IDE + JBoss AS (WildFly 9.0.1). Then I launch the server and all is OK. I would like to know how to set an applicatioin as root context?.
To run my application I have to do:
`http://localhost:8080/demoApp`, but I wanna just do: `http://localhost:8080/`

Below you have a fragment of the code of the file: `standalone.xml`.
I modified it as you can see below but I get: *403 - Forbidden* when going to: `http://localhost:8080/`. Remember that the WildFly server is launched with the Eclipse debugger because I'm on development mode.

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default" />
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"
            redirect-socket="https" />
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="demoApp" />
            <filter-ref name="server-header" />
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header" />
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config />
        <websockets />
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content" />
        <file name="demoApp" path="${jboss.home.dir}/standalone/deployments/demoApp.war" />
    </handlers>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deploy as ROOT.war and disable the default root web app in standalone.xml, the logger tells you the name of the config attribute to change

Answer (score 1):

a better option would be adding

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

into jboss-web.xml